# « Chimères » : nom d'animal composé uniquement de noms d'animaux

Tags: suffixes, zoologie, jeux-de-mots

Je cherche à trouver ce que j'appelle des [*chimères*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chim%C3%A8re_%28mythologie%29), des noms d'animaux composés uniquement de noms d'autres animaux (phonétiquement).

J'en ai trouvé quelques-uns, comme un *chaton* (chat + thon) et un *raton* (rat + thon).

J'ai également trouvé ce qui peut s'apparenter à une « chimère » mais n'en ai pas une : *Racaille* (rat + caille) ne correspond pas à un animal, ce n'est donc pas une chimère. Idem pour *rachat* (rat + chat).

---

Existe-t-il d'autres chimères ? Si oui lesquelles ?

Comment: @close-voters : Je pourrais voter pour fermer cette question au motif qu'elle ne porte pas sur la langue française (sur une propriété de la langue définie par l'imagination de l'OP), mais certainement pas au motif qu'elle est subjective / basée sur des opinions. Il me semble que tout le monde s'entend sur ce que sont les noms des animaux, et la composition  (visiblement phonétique) de tels noms. Pourquoi fermer ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Grands

- Python (pie + thon)
- [Raton](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratons) (rat + thon)
- [Hanneton](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanneton) (âne + thon)
- Serpent (cerf + paon)
- Pivert (pie + ver)
- [Verrat](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/verrat) (ver + rat)

#### Petits en -ton / -let

- Chaton (chat + thon)
- Caneton (cane + thon)
- [Chouetton](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chouetton) (chouette + thon)
- [Truiton](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/truiton) (truie + thon)
- [Muleton](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/muleton) (mule + thon)
- [Rossignolet](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/rossignolet) (rossignol + laie)

Source : [Animaux du wiktionnaire en français](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/Annexe:Animaux_communs_en_fran%C3%A7ais)

Comment: Pourquoi Chapon ?

Comment: Un chapon est un coq. Je laisse Kii déterminer si ça rentre dans sa définition de "nom d'animal" ou pas, mais dans le doute, je suggère.

Comment: Mais pon sonne-t-il comme un nom d'animal ? Le paon fait plus la roue, que le pont...

Comment: Et il semble aussi que le t de pipit se prononce.

Comment: @GAMPUB: Ah pardon. Je n'ai pas entendu *pan* prononcé différement de *pon* depuis des lustres. Bon point. Stéphane : Ah oui, oups, merci.

Comment: Merci beaucoup ! Je n'aurai pas cru qu'il y en avait tant.

Comment: You haven't participated in FL&U lately! Don't leave us!

Comment: @Aerovistae: I'm afraid life already brought me other challenges ;)

Comment: @NikanaReklawyks Alas....thanks for your various contributions, if it turns out to be permanent!

Answer (score 8):

> Python.....   (pie + thon)
>   Serpent... (cerf + paon)
>   Pivert.......   (pie + ver)

**Suggestions d'un autre contributeur:**

> Caneton... (cane+thon)
>   Verrat.....(ver+rat)

Comment: Génial !!! Encore quelques unes et je valide cette réponse !

Comment: Hanneton --> Âne + Thon -- Chimères vivantes : http://animaux.org/chat-ours.htm ; https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rat-taupe_nu

Answer (score 5):

Je ne sais pas si vous cherchez le même mot ou la même prononciation ou un mot composé.

**Voici des mots composés :**

- Poisson-chat
- Araignée-crabe
- Araignée-loup
- Grenouille-léopard
- Grenouille-taureau
- Moqueur-chat (Le *moqueur* est un oiseau)

**Composé + même prononciation :**

- Cochon d'inde (Cochon + dinde)

Comment: chien-loup, requin-tigre, ...

Comment: Techniquement les mots composés pourraient correspondre à ma définition de chimère, je n'y avais pas pensé ! Cependant, je les trouve un peu "facile". J'ai adoré le Cochon-Dinde.

Comment: Je ne sais pas s'ils sont simple mais en tout cas ils existent.